# How to not include layout.haml in sinatra app

Tags: ruby, layout, sinatra

I have a ruby sinatra app that uses haml. I use layout.haml for a common menu across all pages. Let's say I have login.haml, main.haml and reports.haml. I only want to use layout.haml for login.haml and main.haml. How do I exclude layout.haml from reports.haml? thanks

Comment: Please improve the question with more information

Answer (score 9):

Two (and a somewhat) ways:

#### Global

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :haml, :layout => false

  get '/reports' do
    haml :reports
  end
end
```

#### Blacklisting

If the number of routes that do not require layouts are less, then this is a pattern:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  get '/reports' do
    haml :reports, :layout => false
  end

end
```

#### Whitelisting

If the routes that don't need a `layout.haml` file are more, however, Sinatra does not seem to support overriding the global declaration of `set :haml, :layout => false`. I've taken the liberty to open up an [issue](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/727) for this feature as it seems reasonable enough (Hope you won't mind).